# Адаптация absolute блока и картинки

Tags: html, css, position

При уменьшении ширины браузера у абсолютного div'a .block высота изменяется не так, как задумывалась: высота становится больше, чем размер картинки, хотя я всё указывал в процентах для обоих блоков. Подскажите, что делаю не так? Как сделать так, чтобы высота .block при измении ширины браузера была равна высоте картинки. Без использования JavaScript.

Ссылка на codepen ↓↓↓

https://codepen.io/mihail-kamahin/pen/axKdKV

```css
body, p {
  margin: 0;
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section {
  padding: 80px 0;
  background: #ceeeeb;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 30%;
  max-height: 559px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c847021/v847021964/1f4d5a/aWI-FhPfH7I.jpg" alt="" class="image">
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Высоту вообще не указывайте . .

Comment: Не понял, у чего именно не нужно указывать высоту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было `img.image` прописать `display: block`

```css
body, p {
  margin: 0;
}

*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section {
  padding: 80px 0;
  background: #ceeeeb;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 30%;
  max-height: 559px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c847021/v847021964/1f4d5a/aWI-FhPfH7I.jpg" alt="" class="image">
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Или вот еще, пожалуйста, посмотрите, как вариант:

```css
body,
p {
  margin: 0;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section {
  position: relative;
  padding: 80px 0;
  background: #ceeeeb;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.block {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c847021/v847021964/1f4d5a/aWI-FhPfH7I.jpg" alt="" class="image">
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не, это излишне, слишком, но поставлю плюсик